# Hive SQL Cast returning integer

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to cast a string to a decimal and it keeps returning an integer.

The input and expected output is as follows:

```
0            0
14400        144.00
-11800       -118.00
42400        424.00
60200        602.00
217400       2174.00
5000         50.00
```

I am using:

```
Cast(Trim(POLAMNT) as Decimal(10,2)) as POLICYAMNT
```

but it is returning the values without the decimal.

Comment: Don't you need to divide by 100?  `Cast(Trim(POLAMNT) as Decimal(10,2)) / 100.00`?

Comment: Cast(Cast(Trim(POLAMNT) as Decimal(10,2))/100 as Decimal(10,2)) as POLICYAMNT  is what I had to use to get the decimals. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it works, though you shouldn't need to cast twice.

Answer (score 0):

Hive *is* creating something of the right type.  Whatever is printing the results is doing you the favor of removing the `.00`.  SQL is not so friendly.  So, convert the result back to a string:

```
cast(cast(trim(POLAMNT) as decimal(10,2)) as string) as POLICYAMNT
```

This should have exactly two decimal places.

EDIT:

I misread the question.  You seem to just want:

```
cast(trim(POLAMNT) as decimal(10,2)) / 100
```

Comment: I need it to remain as an decimal and not as a string, and this would work if I wanted to keep the two decimal places when there's a 00 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cast(Trim(POLAMNT) as Decimal) / pow(10,2) as POLICYAMNT
```

was the fastest (and cleanest) way to achieve what I needed.